# Can we paint a JTable cell partially?

Tags: java, jtable

Is it possible to paint a JTable cell alone partially?Like 40% of it is green remaining is red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you say, I understand you want to do progress-bar like painting in a JTable cell. if so, you could be interested by [those old Swing examples](http://web.archive.org/web/20040110120752/www2.gol.com/users/tame/swing/examples/JTableExamples6.html).

Comment: Thanks for that but my need is it can start from any part of the cell.Meaning Progress bar starts from 0 to 100 but mine is like a new bar should start in between like 40%.IN that case will progress bar be useful?

Comment: As the above example no more works, an other one can be accessed at http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.fr/2008/03/jprogressbar-in-jtable-cell.html

Comment: I have a better solution @Ridduel do you want to try that too?

Answer (score 2):

In a Jtable you can implement your own cellrenderer more on Jtables in

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

in the renderer you can paint anyway you want

Comment: Using renderer we can paint anyway inside intercells.What I am talking about is intracell

Comment: You got me confused there, what are intercells and intracells and how do they related to a Jtable with cells and borders between cells ?

Comment: ok let me be clear.Forget intra and intercells.Imagine I have a table with 3 rows and 3 columns represented by A1,A2,A3 B1,B2,B3 and C1,C2,C3 and take the cell C1 for example.Now this cell should be colored in such a way that the first 20% of the cell is white and the remaining is green.Cell C2 should have the first 50% colored and the next 50% as white.Now while coloring there should not be any number or % displayed (which is why progress bar will fail as it will contain the %)